# TableLayout и элементы на нем во весь экран

Tags: java, android, вёрстка

Доброго времени суток!
Как сделать что бы элементы (в моем случае кнопки) в контейнере TableLayout занимали все пространство экрана. В ширину я решил проблему через использование свойства layout_weight, а вот как в высоту - не могу понять.
В table layout у меня лежит три TableRow, в котором в свою очередь имеется по четыре кнопки.

Answer (score 0):

Может использовать GridLayout - этот менеджер раскладывает компоненты по сетке...
http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/layout/gridlayout.php

Comment: Ну это как вариант,но а как сделать что бы на весь экран элементы растянуть?

Comment: Я в андройде не работал никогда, а про менеджер этот только читал:  
[http://www.skipy.ru/technics/layouts.html#grid](http://www.skipy.ru/technics/layouts.html#grid)

Comment: "layout_weight"  
может по аналогии layout_height?

Comment: зачем отвечать, если вы не знаете ответа ... weight - вес, а не width - ширина